# Looping through HTML elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML/Bootstrap form (dynamically generated):

```
<div id="date_fields">
<div class="form-group removeclass0">
    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control dateKey" name="dateKey[]" value="revision">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input type="text" class="form-control dateValue" name="dateValue[]" value="2010-09-20">
                <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_date_fields(0);"> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
<div class="form-group removeclass1">
    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            <input type="text" class="form-control dateKey" name="dateKey[]" value="publication">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6 nopadding">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group"> 
                <input type="text" class="form-control dateValue" name="dateValue[]" value="2008-05-21">
                <div class="input-group-btn"> 
                    <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" onclick="remove_date_fields(1);"> 
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus" aria-hidden="true"></span> 
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</div>
```

Here is JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/mleontenko/mmk9zo4L/

I need to loop through this form and store dateKey and dateValue pairs into an array that looks like this:

```
[
    {
        "dateKey":"revision",
        "dateValue":"2010-09-20"
    },
    {
         "dateKey":"publication",
         "dateValue":"2008-05-21"
    }
]
```

What is the best way to do this using jQuery or plain JavaScript?

Comment: Please define "_the best_".

Comment: Any simple solution that works :)

Comment: But, but ... that is not "the best", that's "any" ..?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var keys = [];
    var values = [];
    var res = [];
    $.each($("#date_fields").find(".dateKey"), function(i, key) {
            keys[i] = $(".dateKey:eq("+i+")").val();
    });

    $.each($("#date_fields").find(".dateValue"), function(i, value) {
      values[i] = $(".dateValue:eq("+i+")").val();
    });


    $.each($("#date_fields").find(".dateValue"), function(i) {
      res[i] = {"dateKey" : keys[i], "dateValue": values[i]};
    });
    $("#result").text(JSON.stringify(res));
});
```

JSFiddle: [Working js fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mmk9zo4L/10/)